# MongoDB working with references

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am a newbie to nosql world and I am stuck during the designing of my database.I am developing an app where there are two collections,

1. User
2. Leave

When a user  applies for leave ,leave details will be added to leave collection and the leaveID(Mongo generated) will be added to the user collection depending on which user applied for leave.

Now my question is for adding the _id to the user collection ,Should i write one more query or is there any way to auto fill the user collection when a document is added to the leave Collection. ie should i write 2 queries to insert into the leave and user collection or with only one query the task could be completed.

I am using java driver for interacting with db.

Comment: A sql database might be more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Try to keep user data in one document. What you are trying to do is make nosql database actually sql. To much relational databases I guess.

Comment: using relational db is not an option i have coz of project constaints

Answer (score 1):

In mongodb, with that collection structure, you'll have two use two requests, yes. One for inserting `leave`, another for inserting leave reference to a user document.

You could do with one request if your leaves were embedded in a user, but that might not make sense, according to your other requirements.